# Explanation of Analog Input Module

Tags: analog, input, plc, module

I'm trying to wire this module. I'm just confused as to what the difference is between the two triangles and how would I connect them?

[image]

Comment: Would you please add in the make and model of the thing you are using, and preferably a link to manual to figure out what it does.

Comment: Here's the link for the tech specs: https://cdn.automationdirect.com/static/specs/p216ad1.pdf

Comment: Ignore everything on the right; that's all stuff happening inside the unit.  For wiring it, just follow the text on the left.   The battery is your 24V source.

Comment: the difference is equal to the battery voltage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That appears to be internal to the module, likely +24VDC and 0VDC. If so then you should only need to deal with the pinout on the left.

Comment: Thank you! Just for future reference, what exactly does the white triangle and black triangle stand for?

Comment: @Chris You need to ask the manufacturer about that. Maybe they don't know either why they chose those symbols.

Answer (score 0):

The white triangle is the analog common reference net, often called “ground” or “0V”.

The black triangle represents a connection to the positive supply rail.

The connection of two lines to the black triangle is unfortunate and confusing. It looks as if the black triangle was some sort of a differential stage or an op-amp. It’s not. The two (+) lines should first connect together using a dot, and only a single line should be shown entering the black triangle.